# Automating Email Dispatch with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, gmail

I am seeking assistance with a Google Apps Script that I’m trying to set up to automate email sending from a Google Sheet. My goal is to have the script send emails automatically whenever the `Status` column in my sheet is updated to `Send`.

Here’s what I’ve done so far:

I’ve created a Google Sheet with columns for `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email`, and `Status`.

I’ve written a script that is supposed to send emails when the `Status` column is updated to ‘Send’. However, I’m encountering issues with the script not triggering as expected. I’m not a developer, so I’m finding it challenging to troubleshoot the problem on my own.

Could someone please review my script and provide guidance on what might be going wrong? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var firstName = row[0];
    var lastName = row[1];
    var emailAddress = row[2];
    var emailSent = row[3];
    if (emailSent == 'Gửi') { // Chỉ gửi email khi cột 'Status' là 'Gửi'
      var subject = 'Chủ đề Email của Bạn';
      var message = createEmailTemplate(firstName, lastName);
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", { htmlBody: message });
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue('Đã gửi');
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}

function createEmailTemplate(firstName, lastName) {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('EmailTemplate');
  htmlTemplate.firstName = firstName;
  htmlTemplate.lastName = lastName;
  return htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

Comment: Can you share what you mean by `encountering issues with the script not triggering as expected`? When I run your code in the Google Apps Script Editor, it seems to be working properly. If what you'd like to do is run the script whenever the column is set to `Send`, you can use the [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SUGGESTED SOLUTION

*Note: It seems like [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) won't work for this because it requires authorization, and as per [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions):*

> They cannot access [services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services) that require [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization). For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the [Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail) requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the [Language service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language), which is anonymous.

Instead, use [Manage triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually) to run the function. Click on **Triggers** > **+ Add Trigger** on the left of the Google Apps Script Editor.

#### SAMPLE TRIGGER IMAGE

[image]

#### SPREADSHEET

[image]

#### GMAIL

[image]

Comment: Did you use the code I wrote or a new code? I tried your solution but it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I used the one you provided, and this is a [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBErf.png) of it. Can you share what's not working?

Comment: thank you for your help,  I found my problem. I just need change the word 'Gửi' => 'Gui' and it run.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that your issue's been resolved! If my answer helped you with your question, please click the accept button on the left, which is the check icon, and upvote it. By doing so, other people in the community who may have the same concern as you would know how their concern would be resolved. If it's unavailable, feel free to tell me. [How to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the function **[onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)** in order for it to be enter code hereautomatically triggered whenever a value is edited in the spreadsheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  // If the value is edited is in the status column (4th column) in the the sheet which has your data, only thencontinue with further operations.
  // Change Sheet1 to whatever is the name of your sheet.
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1' && column == 4) {
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      var row = data[i];
      var firstName = row[0];
      var lastName = row[1];
      var emailAddress = row[2];
      var emailSent = row[3];
      if (emailSent == 'Gửi') { // Chỉ gửi email khi cột 'Status' là 'Gửi'
        var subject = 'Chủ đề Email của Bạn';
        var message = createEmailTemplate(firstName, lastName);
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", { htmlBody: message });
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 4).setValue('Đã gửi');
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    }
  }
}

function createEmailTemplate(firstName, lastName) {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('EmailTemplate');
  htmlTemplate.firstName = firstName;
  htmlTemplate.lastName = lastName;
  return htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

This should work. Just in case you are still stuck, let me know the exact issue/error from logs.

Comment: thank you for your help but it still not work. This is what i get when i run the script.

     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
     onEdit       @ Mã.gs:2

Comment: The error is because you're running the function manually. You don't have to run the function onEdit manually or by a time based trigger. It will automatically run whenever a value is edited in the sheet. Just copy the code as it is, change the sheet name to your one. That's it. If you don't see the emails coming, go to the executions of onEdit and see the logs to find what's the error/

Comment: I think the [Strict inequality (!==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality) operator on `if (sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1' && column == 4)` was intended to be the [Equality (==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) operator. Would that be correct, or did I just not get the logic of your code correctly?

Comment: No, sheet.getName() returns a string. So, the strict inequality is not an issue.